# Setting contentMode of UIButton within custom UITableViewCell shows no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am creating mu custom UITableViewCells in `- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` like so:

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Using InterfaceBuilder I have set the content mode of the two buttons contained within this cell's xib to `AspectFit` but they are being shown in a way that does not preserve the aspect ratio. So then I added the following code to this class:

```
- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    NSLog(@"running initwithstyle");
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [[deleteButton imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [[saveButton imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This function isn't even running. I also tried subclassing `displayLayer` but apparently that is not being called either. What function should I subclass so that I can set the content mode of buttons within my Xib, and why is setting the content mode in the Xib having no effect?

Comment: You can save yourself a line of code up there. Rather than creating an array and then getting object at index 0, just do `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] firstObject]`

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the code in `-(void)awakeFromNib`. The reason it does not execute in `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` is because that's not how you're creating your custom cell.

I believe the reason that setting the content mode in the xib has no effect is because that is setting the content mode on the button rather than on the button's image view.